# Recording with Bluetooth Mic

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-recording

After connecting with paired devices, Bluetooth is not taking his Mic, instead it is taking mobile's Mic
Below is my code

```
public abstract class BluetoothHeadsetUtils {
    private Context mContext;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;
    private BluetoothDevice mConnectedHeadset;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    private boolean mIsCountDownOn;
    private boolean mIsStarting;
    private boolean mIsOnHeadsetSco;
    private boolean mIsStarted;
    ExminatingHelper exminatingHelper = ExminatingHelper.getInstance();
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothHeadsetUtils";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public BluetoothHeadsetUtils(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * Call this to start BluetoothHeadsetUtils functionalities.
     *
     * @return The return value of startBluetooth() or startBluetooth11()
     */
    public boolean start() {
        if (!mIsStarted) {
            mIsStarted = true;
            mIsStarted = startBluetooth();
            /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                mIsStarted = startBluetooth();
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
               // mIsStarted = startBluetooth11();
            }*/
        }

        return mIsStarted;
    }

    /**
     * Should call this on onResume or onDestroy.
     * Unregister broadcast receivers and stop Sco audio connection
     * and cancel count down.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (mIsStarted) {
            mIsStarted = false;
            stopBluetooth();
            /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                stopBluetooth();
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
               // stopBluetooth11();
            }*/
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return true if audio is connected through headset.
     */
    public boolean isOnHeadsetSco() {
        return mIsOnHeadsetSco;
    }

    public abstract void onHeadsetDisconnected();

    public abstract void onHeadsetConnected();

    public abstract void onScoAudioDisconnected();

    public abstract void onScoAudioConnected();


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private boolean startBluetooth() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startBluetooth"); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // Device support bluetooth
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()) {
                mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED));

                mIsCountDownOn = true;
                // mCountDown repeatedly tries to start bluetooth Sco audio connection.
                mCountDown.start();

                // need for audio sco, see mBroadcastReceiver
                mIsStarting = true;

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private CountDownTimer mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // When this call is successful, this count down timer will be canceled.
            mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();

            Log.d(TAG, "\nonTick start bluetooth Sco"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Calls to startBluetoothSco() in onStick are not successful.
            // Should implement something to inform user of this failure
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "\nonFinish fail to connect to headset audio"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "synthetic-access"})
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            int getRecrodingDevice = exminatingHelper.getRecordingDevice();
            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
                mConnectedHeadset = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = mConnectedHeadset.getBluetoothClass();
                if (bluetoothClass != null) {
                    // Check if device is a headset. Besides the 2 below, are there other
                    // device classes also qualified as headset?
                    int deviceClass = bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass();
                    if (deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE
                            || deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET
                    || deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HEADPHONES
                    || deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_LOUDSPEAKER
                    ) {
                        // start bluetooth Sco audio connection.
                        // Calling startBluetoothSco() always returns faIL here,
                        // that why a count down timer is implemented to call
                        // startBluetoothSco() in the onTick.
                        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                        mIsCountDownOn = true;
                        mCountDown.start();

                        // override this if you want to do other thing when the device is connected.
                        onHeadsetConnected();
                    }
                }

                Log.d(TAG, mConnectedHeadset.getName() + " connected"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            } else if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset disconnected"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                    mIsCountDownOn = false;
                    mCountDown.cancel();
                }

                // override this if you want to do other thing when the device is disconnected.
                onHeadsetDisconnected();
            } else if (action.equals(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED) && getRecrodingDevice != 2) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE,
                        AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_ERROR);

                if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mIsOnHeadsetSco = true;

                    if (mIsStarting) {
                        // When the device is connected before the application starts,
                        // ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED will not be received, so call onHeadsetConnected here
                        mIsStarting = false;
                        onHeadsetConnected();
                    }

                    if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                        mIsCountDownOn = false;
                        mCountDown.cancel();
                    }

                    // override this if you want to do other thing when Sco audio is connected.
                    onScoAudioConnected();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Sco connected"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                } else if (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sco disconnected"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                    // Always receive SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED on call to startBluetooth()
                    // which at that stage we do not want to do anything. Thus the if condition.
                    if (!mIsStarting) {
                        mIsOnHeadsetSco = false;

                        // Need to call stopBluetoothSco(), otherwise startBluetoothSco()
                        // will not be successful.
                        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();

                        // override this if you want to do other things when Sco audio is disconnected.
                        onScoAudioDisconnected();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void stopBluetooth() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopBluetooth"); //$NON-NLS-1$

        if (mIsCountDownOn) {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mCountDown.cancel();
        }

        // Need to stop Sco audio connection here when the app
        // change orientation or close with headset still turns on.
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    }
}
}
```

This works well when using the phone in a normal fashion. However, it does not detect the presence of a Bluetooth headset and still uses the phone's own microphone even when the headset is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clip of mine, there was this Bluetooth receiver class shared on SO, but it didn't work well with me (long story short, don't use the  (state == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED) because when I trigger it via clicking the button, there's usually a false positive).
Try following the logs..

and on

```
onHeadsetConnected();
```

like

```
private void onHeadsetConnected(){
       speech.startListening(theIntent);
}
```

while to capture when you have "disconnected", instead of counting SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED, just capture onError, onPartialResult, onResult and recheck whether the device is still there .. as so, or .. you know .. recheck it when you need to listen to it again instead of when it's done ..

```
mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectionState(mConnectedHeadset) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED
```

And I do this to ensure I'm connecting to the right headset (that has a mic!)

```
if (mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices().size()>0) {
        mConnectedHeadset = null;
        for (int i=0;i<mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices().size(); i ++){
            int deviceClass = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices().get(i).getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass();
            switch (deviceClass){
                case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE:
                case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO:
                case BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_MICROPHONE:
                case BluetoothClass.Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE:
                    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    mConnectedHeadset = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices().get(i);
                    registerReceiver(mHeadsetBroadcastReceiver,
                            new IntentFilter(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED));
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you / or someone .. since I tried to implement that class, way too much of a hassle, so I just took parts of it into my activity and  use what I needed (definitely didn't need support for old android)